# Find the number of solutions to $n_1 +n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 12$ when values of $n_k$ have restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Find the number of solutions in integers to

$$n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 12$$

satisfying $0 \le n_1 \le 4, 0 \le n_2 \le 5, 0 \le n_3 \le 8, \text{and } 0\le n_4 \le 9$

I'm having trouble with this. I can see that $C(12 + 4 - 1, 12)$ is the solution when the only restriction is $n_k \ge 0$. However, I'm unsure how to get to (the textbook solution):

$C(12+4-1,12) - [C(7+4-1,7)+C(6+4 -1, 6)+C(3+4-1,3)+C(2+4-1,2)-C(1+4-1,1)]$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Comment: Presumably this is from a course that wants you to do it a certain way, but my preferred method would be to calculate the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $$\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}\frac{x^6-1}{x-1}\frac{x^9-1}{x-1}\frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}.$$

Comment: I have a working knowledge of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle. I've used it to solve counting problems involving up to three sets.

Here is what I am thinking: $C(12 + 4 -1,12)$ is the count for the number of solutions with any integer values. The other $C(k + t -1, k)$ expressions count the number of solutions with various restrictions on them. I'm not sure what those restrictions are. But since we are subtracting solutions from the count of all solutions in integers, the solutions we are subtracting must be solutions that do not satisfy the inequalities.  

Does that seem plausible?

Comment: @GregMartin: It comes from a chapter on combinations. I don't understand your solution. I'm certainly not opposed to it. My hope, however, is to understand the combinations theory they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ denote nonnegative solutions to $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=12$ and $A_i$ denote those solutions where the upper bound on $n_i$ is *violated*, then inclusion/exclusion gives
$$|\overline{A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4}|=|A|-(|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|+|A_4|)+(|A_1\cap A_2|+\cdots)-\cdots\\
=\binom{12+4-1}{12}-\left(\binom{7+4-1}7+\binom{6+4-1}6+\binom{3+4-1}3+\binom{2+4-1}2\right)+\binom{1+4-1}1$$
where e.g. $|A_1|=\binom{7+4-1}7$ because the solutions there can be recast as solutions to $(m_1+5)+n_2+n_3+n_4=12$ with $m_1,n_i\ge0$ or $m_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=7$, and omitted terms are because they are empty (i.e. they reduce to a sum of nonnegative integers to a negative integer).

Comment: So there are four cases where only one of the upperbounds on $n_i$ is violated:
 $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 7$ when $n_1$'s condition is violated.
 $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 6$ when $n_2$'s condition is violated.
 $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 3$ when $n_3$'s condition is violated.
 $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 2$ when $n_4$'s condition is violated.

And there is one case where two of the upperbounds on $n_i$ is violated:
 $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 1$ when both $n_1$'s and $n_2$'s condition is violated.

I don't understand your remark about omitted terms and the sum of nonnegative integers.

Comment: I realised my remark "$n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 = 1$ when both $n_1$'s and $n_2$'s condition is violated" cannot be right. $C(1+4-1,1)$ is being added to the number of solutions.

Comment: @WarrenTheRabbit the first four cases you list are actually those where _at least_ one upper bound is violated, and the fifth case is where _at least_ the $n_{1,2}$ bounds are violated. This is why inclusion/exclusion works. If you tried working out omitted terms you'd end up with a binomial coefficient that sums to zero.